# Using automator, only part of CSV is read

Tags: r, bash, shell, locale, automator

I am trying to use automator to run a shell script and read in a CSV to then transform the CSV and write the result into a file. The code looks like this:

***Unformatted (as in Automator)***

```
Rscript -e "data<-read.table('/Users/User1/Desktop/test/basedata.csv',sep='\\\t',skip=5,header=TRUE,fileEncoding='UCS-2LE');data <- data[,c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6')];data <- data[data[,'Col3']=='Criterion A',];data <- data[order(data[,'Col4']),];write.csv(data,'/Users/User1/Desktop/test/Done.csv',row.names=FALSE);"
```

***Formatted***

```
Rscript -e 
"data<-read.table(
   '/Users/User1/Desktop/test/basedata.csv',
   sep='\\\t',
   skip=5,
   header=TRUE,
   fileEncoding='UCS-2LE'
);
data <- data[,c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6')];
data <- data[data[,'Col3']=='Criterion A',];
data <- data[order(data[,'Col4']),];
write.csv(data,'/Users/User1/Desktop/test/Done.csv',row.names=FALSE);"
```

When I run the part within quotes in R from the command line, I get a file of about 3MB. When I run the code within Automator the script runs fine, but I only get ~50 lines. When I run the same script from the command line as above I even get an error saying:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in "l3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6')];data <- data[data[,'Col3']=='Criterion A',];data<-data[order(data[,'Col4']),];write.csv(data,'"
```

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***: Apparently it has to do with the encoding. When I take out all German Umlauts (ü,ä,ö) the problem disappears. When I specify the fileEncoding in write.csv I get errors (in Automator with no exception). When I use the same code in R it works fine. There seems to be some layer in between automator and the shell script that's causing this.

***EDIT 2***: I am starting to think it has to do with the locale. I tried

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;LC_CTYPE=UTF-8;LANG=en_US.utf8;
```

In front of the shell script, with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use automator to run a shell script. You can then run your R script from within your bash script using R Batch.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    cd absolute/path/of/R/File/Directory
    R CMD BATCH scriptfile outputfile
```